# C# Unity, Named arguments syntax outside of functions?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax

I'm very confused about what seems to be Named argument format being declared outside of a function like this

> var acc : Vector3 = Vector3.zero;

Here is the full code snippet for accelerometer readings

```
var period : float = 0.0;
var acc : Vector3 = Vector3.zero;
for (var evnt : iPhoneAccelerationEvent in iPhoneInput.accelerationEvents) {
    acc += evnt.acceleration * evnt.deltaTime;
    period += evnt.deltaTime;
}
if (period > 0)
    acc *= 1.0/period;
return acc;
```

The code was directly lifted from Unity's manual [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/Manual/MobileInput.html)

Comment: i think that's typescript. a newer version using c# seems to be [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html)